# Python Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional pandas trying to get two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create 2 columns but I am getting an error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Error: *raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional*

```
Questions = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3','Q4','Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9', 'Q10']
#model_1 = RBM(nv,nh) ## ERROR!!!

Weight = rbm.W.detach().numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions': Questions,
                   'Weights': Weight
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pd.DataFrame line looks fine, so it seems that the issue is probably that Weight has more than one dimension. You can check the dimensions of Weight with Weight.shape. If it is two dimensional with 1 as the second dimension (for example (10,1)), you can reshape it with

```
Weight = Weight.reshape(Weight.shape[0],)
```

Comment: I got an error.  ** ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1000 into shape (100,) ** . What should i do

Comment: The line I made is for if the Weight.shape is two-dimensional with 1 as the second dimension. It seems like when you check Weight.shape, the dimensions are probably actually (100, 10). You should think about what exactly you want in the Weight column, and look at whether that is the information that is in the Weight array.

Comment: Fyi if this answered your question, you can click the check mark next to the answer. Otherwise it will continue to show up as unanswered.